# Connectify Hotspot not working on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, connectify

I am using connectify Hotspot for my windows 8.1 laptop. Everything was working fine but today it stopped working suddenly. This is the screenshot of the connectify interface.[image].

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling connectify on my laptop but it doesn't work.How to solve this problem?

Comment: Based on the error your wireless adapter is disabled or not installed.

Comment: yeah how can I enable the wireless adapter again? I tried a couple of things but nothing worked.